# Hide Keyboard but keep UIToolBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I can add the same toolbar to the main view and to the keyboard and then hide one or another but it seems far from perfect.

Can I make the toolbar always visible at the bottom of the screen and then slide it up on the keyboard when it appears and slide down when the keyboard is being dismissed?

Comment: Is this toolbar a custom UITabBar? Or a custom UIview that acts like tab bar

Comment: It's UIToolBar,

Comment: You can do this, but with a custom tab bar view. There are some youtube vids in how to make one of these. However fair warning, to give it this behaviour is very tricky and can get messy considering you're allowing your user to switch VC's while they are inputing something.. might make for a UX some users could find displeasing or aggravating if they happen to hit on of the tab bar icons while inputing text.. thus switching their UI to something that doesn't show what they were doing in the first place.